# Hermitian Matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, hermitian-matrices

Can you show that the range space and the null space of a Hermitian matrix are mutually orthogonal. I was reading a conference paper and they used it too easily I suppose. Can you please prove.

Comment: Do you know that the rowspace and nullspace are orthogonal?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra

Answer (score 4):

Let $H$ be a Hermitian matrix. Let $u$ be a vector such that $Hu=0$, and $v$ be any vector.

$$\left<u,Hv\right>=\left<H^*u,v\right>=\left<Hu,v\right>=\left<0,v\right>=0$$